# UITableView: on row selection load a second UITableView with related data

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have two UITableViews on one view and would like to implement the following logic:
- when a row is selected on tableView1 populate tableView2 with related information

I have set both UITableViews delegate and datasource, and am processing the initial population of tableView1 and didSelectRowAtIndexPath on tableView1. I am also checking to make sure the right UITableView is being handled i.e. tableView == MyTableViewVariable

Within handling didSelectRowAtIndexPath for tableView1 I finish off by calling [tableView2 reloadData] expecting that this would initiate the chain of method calls to force tableView2 to load up. But calling that method doesn't do anything.

A couple of posts indicate to me that people have got this working by putting a delay in their code, or forcing the call to be made from the main thread.

Can anyone point me to the best way to do this?

Cheers, James

Answer (score 0):

use tags. But Its easier if you have two separate view controllers.

```
UITableView *a, *b; 
a.tag = 0; 
b.tag = 1; 

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if(tv.tag==0 && indexpath.row==0)
      b.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
      [self.view addSubView:b];
      [b reloadData]; 
}
```